# Jade Mixin - with object manipulation

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, mixins

I am attempting to programmatically display/render objects within a jade template, achieved by passing an array of objects to the view. The goal is to display a grid view with a maximum of 3 items/objects per row. I encountered an issue with nested elements self closing within in-line code blocks.

I have started experimenting with Mixins in order to achieve my goal:

```
mixin testCase_Columns(obj)
- for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
   if (i%3==0)
     div.row
        +renderObj(i, obj)
```

The above logic identifies if the current object number within my array is divisible by 3. This is how i intend to control rendering 3 items/objects per row. From here i pass the object and counter variable to a second mixin:

```
mixin renderObj(i, obj)
  - for(var xx = 0; xx <3 ; xx++)
      div.col-lg-4
        p='Object:' + obj[i].proj
        **- i++**
```

Above, i render three columns and add 1 to my counter 'i', 'i' in this case is used to state my object array key.

The problem i have is when i include the i++ increment statement jade returns the error:

```
type error: Cannot read property 'proj' of undefined
```

However i have performed various tests including accessing and printing each object by manually stating key:

```
obj[1].proj / obj[2].proj / obj[3].proj for example.
```

When I attempt to add an increment statement it blows up in my face.

I am still learning node / jade etc. Perhaps my coding is incorrect. I am aware the above code statement lack fundamental logic to render a final row correctly which contains less than three objects but at the moment i am only testing.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Changing 'i++' to: 'i+=1; fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe get away from that "row" thinking. Correct me if i'm wrong but what you have there is obviously a "list" of objects. So why don't you just use a list-markup instead of unnecessarily chopping a collection of objects in smaller parts?

```
<ul>
    <li> Object 1 </li>
    <li> Object 2 </li>
    <li> Object 3 </li>
    <li> Object [...] </li>
    <li> Object 20 </li>
</ul>
```

It's as simple as that. And now you just have to style that list. In [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) this is called [block grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block-grid.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that you end up trying to access the array outside its boundaries. Thus you accidentally try to access the property of a non-existent object which is an error in JavaScript.

Your code is a bit convoluted. But what is happening is something like this. Consider an array with the length 5. Your `renderObj` mixin is then being run twice. The first time it starts at the index 0 and increments up to 2. The second time it's called with `i == 3` as that also satisfies your `i % 3 == 0` if statement. But it then increments `i` up to 5 and tries to access `obj[5].proj`. But `obj` has length 5 and therefore has no content beyond an index of `4`. Thus you get the error.

I'd take a slightly different approach without using mixins that still works with Jade's indentation. I avoid the index problem by checking if the index is withing the arrays boundaries.

The following Jade template

```
table
  - for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(obj.length / 3); i++)
    tr
      - for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        if (i * 3 + j < obj.length)
          td= obj[i * 3 + j]
```

Produces this HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Yo</td>
    <td>what</td>
    <td>is</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>up</td>
    <td>end</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When run with the following command line options: `jade test.jade -O "{ obj: ['Yo', 'what', 'is', 'up', 'end'] }"`.

The above works as you want it to but as mchlslzmnn mentions you should consider if you data is actually something that should be marked up in table form. The W3C spec states the following about the `table` tag:

> The table element represents data with more than one dimension, in the form of a table.

If your data is one dimensional and the order doesn't matter you should use `ul` instead.